# Android PrintManager - how can I render low-res pages for preview, but high-res for printing?

Tags: android, printing

I am using PrintManager and PrintDocumentAdapter for printing in my app.  I've followed this example:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/PrintCustomContent.java

I need to render the pages as bitmaps, which works, but it's slow.  I want to render them at low resolution for the preview, and high resolution for actual printing.  I can't see how to do that.  In fact, PrintDocumentAdapter.onWrite() seems to be called only once.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing custom contents, can you create an image file and hand it to the OS to print as in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos.html#image)?